# Create Outlook appointment from Excel (Office 2013 and Office 2016)

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have code for creating Outlook appointment from Excel.

The problem is that …

- Office 2013 uses *Microsoft Word **15.0** Object Library* and
- Office 2016/365 uses *Microsoft Word **16.0** Object Library*.

Then there is an error about missing reference in Office 2013 version.

Is there any way to make it work in both versions Office 2013 and Office 2016?

Here is my code:

```
Sub CreateNewOutlookAppointment()     
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector

    Set olAppt = Nothing
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olAppt = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    Set myInspector = olAppt.GetInspector 
    myInspector.Activate

    With olAppt
        .Subject = "Review" & ", " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("P23").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Templates").Range("M202:M223").Copy
        .Display
        .GetInspector.WordEditor.Windows(1).Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPASTERTF

        .Attachments.Add Environ("temp") & "\" & _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("AK2").Value & ", " & _
        "Bid review" & ".pdf"  
    End With

    Application.SendKeys ("%HOM")  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *Late Binding* instead of *Early Binding* and completely remove the reference to the Outlook library. See [Using early binding and late binding in Automation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation).

*Note that in Late Binding you don't have Intelli Sense Tool Tips anymore. And you cannot use any Outlook enumerations.*

---

#### What does that mean for your code?

Therfore declare your Outlook variables as `Object` and use late bindinding to create the Outlook application: `Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`.

Note that you cannot use the Outlook enumerations like `olAppointmentItem` anymore. Instead you need to use their actual value (which in case of `olAppointmentItem` is `1`)

```
Set olAppt = olApp.CreateItem(1)
```

or you need to define them as constants to use them:

```
Const olAppointmentItem As Integer = 1
Set olAppt = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
```

The same for `wdPASTERTF` which is also `1` according to [WdPasteDataType enumeration (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdpastedatatype)

```
Sub CreateNewOutlookAppointment()        
    Dim olApp As Object
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olAppt As Object
    Set olAppt = olApp.CreateItem(1) 'you cannot use `olAppointmentItem` in late binding (unless you declare it as constant)

    Dim myInspector As Object
    Set myInspector = olAppt.GetInspector
    myInspector.Activate

    With olAppt
        .Subject = "Review" & ", " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("P23").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Templates").Range("M202:M223").Copy
        .Display
        .GetInspector.WordEditor.Windows(1).Selection.PasteAndFormat 1 'wdPASTERTF = 1

        .Attachments.Add Environ("temp") & "\" & _
                         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("AK2").Value & ", " & _
                         "Bid review" & ".pdf"
    End With

    Application.SendKeys ("%HOM")
End Sub
```